# How can I be sure that my browser does not exfiltrate my passwords to some server?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, corporate-policy

This is my first question and I dont even know if it is the right place. If this is an off-topic just mark it as off-topic, don't go crazy and downvote. :P

But how can I detect if my browser is not storing my passwords in some server, for later use against me. :D How can I trust my browsers privacy policy?

And also I am seeking something like `lsof` in linux.

P.S. I must be looking too paranoidy, but I am too curious :)

Comment: I guess you're looking for an `lsof` equivalent in _Windows_, as it actually is running on Linux. I suggest you go look at [FileMon from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)

Comment: i don't think you can be 100% sure of anything on the Internet... But I am just a dog...what the hell do I know about internet. whof! (NoOneKnowsYouAreDogOnTheInternet.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, in order to be 100% sure, one would have to either read the browser source-code entirely (in case of open source software) or reverse-engineer it to understand what it does (in case of closed source software).

More realistically though, major browsers (e.g. IE, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Chrome) are probably the most studied software by security researchers, scrutinized in every way to find vulnerabilities and understand their behaviour. If one browser was capturing and sending user passwords to remote servers, this would have been detected.

Another reason why you should not be scared of that is: why would they do that? No matter what the benefit would be, can you imagine the risk they'd be taking by doing so ? If you're a browser editor and you get caught doing that, you can say goodbye to your business.

Comment: <blockquote>If you're a browser editor and you get caught doing that, you can say goodbye to your business. </blockquote> &middash; You're right. Thanks, now I can sleep without worries :)

Comment: You would also need to check that your browser was the browser you thought it was, i.e. build it yourself or check build hashes of others. @SylapAliyev

Comment: @jhoyla Of course! Although I don't know how to built anything other than my simple cpp and java projects. :) And did you notice your user id is 12121 (palindrome?) :)